# Запросы к Instagram Api

Tags: сетевое-программирование, instagram-api

Всем привет! Кто знает, есть ли возможность у Instagram Api автоматической регистрации нового пользователя? Скажем написать своё ПО, которое будет отправлять запросы к Api с данными пользователей и регистрировать их через Api. Не нашёл точного описания в документации, но знаю что есть такие реализации.

Comment: если реализации регистрации ботов и есть, то работают они не через апи ИГ

Comment: Я вот тоже так подумал, но есть одна прога Perfect studio называется. Они предоставляют возможность регистрации сразу нескольких пользователей. Я задал вопрос в техподдержку, типа как они это делают, ведь Instagram Api не предоставляет такой возможности, но они уверяют обратное